# What does pulling on syrup (in the semi-solid state) do to the texture/taste?

Tags: sugar, candy

I have seen this done at candy shops before, where the syrup is pulled/stretched 10s of times before they are allowed to cool off.

What chemically does this do to the sugar? How does this affect the taste?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It aerates the sugar ([you do the same for taffy](http://www.exploratorium.edu/cooking/candy/taffy-story.html)) - adding tiny bubbles in the final product.

It makes the finished product lighter and chewier instead of denser and hard.